# D3 Tree orientation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with the D3 Tree layout, similar to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrkrympk/), the only problem is that I need the orientation of each node to start at the top left of the layout and not on the top center.

```
var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {         
    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
});
```

Something similar to this: [image]

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092).

```
// Compute the new tree layout.
var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

// figure out the placement of the "top-most" node at each depth
var nodeMap = {};
nodes.forEach(function(d) { 
  if (!nodeMap[d.depth] || d.x < nodeMap[d.depth]){
    nodeMap[d.depth] = d.x;
  }
});
// shift all nodes up
nodes.forEach(function(d) { 
  d.y = d.depth * 100;
  d.x -= nodeMap[d.depth];
});
```

---

This produces:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Tree Example</title>

    <style>
 
 .node {
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text {
   font: 12px sans-serif;
 }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
 
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 
<script>

var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of B",
            "parent": "Level 2: B"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of B",
            "parent": "Level 2: B"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
 width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var i = 0,
 duration = 750,
 root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
 .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
 .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
  
update(root);

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
   links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  var nodeMap = {};
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { 
    if (!nodeMap[d.depth] || d.x < nodeMap[d.depth]){
      nodeMap[d.depth] = d.x;
    }
  });
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { 
    d.y = d.depth * 100;
    d.x -= nodeMap[d.depth];
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
   .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
   .attr("r", 1e-6)
   .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
   .attr("r", 10)
   .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
   .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
   .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   })
   .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
 d.x0 = d.x;
 d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
 d._children = d.children;
 d.children = null;
  } else {
 d.children = d._children;
 d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

not only the nodes (x,y) should be interchanged but also the links connecting the nodes i.e.

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(d) {return [d.y,d.x];});
```

Comment: If the (x, y) nodes are interchanged then the tree would appear to have a hierarchy of (top center) orientation and not a (top left) orientation, if I am not mistaken, and that's not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this example i made

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var data = {
        "name" : "A",
        "children" : [
        {
            "name" : "B",
            "children" : [
            {
                "name" : "F"
            },
            {
                "name" : "G"
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "C",
            "children" : [
            {
                "name" : "H"
            },
            {
                "name" : "I"
            },
            {
                "name" : "J"
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "D",
            "children" : [
            {
                "name" : "K"
            },
            {
                "name" : "L"
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "E"
        }
        ]
    };

    var canvas = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width",600)
        .attr("height",500)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform","translate(50,50)");

    var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
        .size([400,400]);

    var nodes = cluster.nodes(data);
    var links = cluster.links(nodes);

    var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
            .attr("class","node")
            .attr("transform",function(d) {return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"});

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r",5)
        .attr("fill","silver");

    node.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {return d.name;});

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) {return [d.y,d.x];});

    canvas.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
            .attr("class","link")
            .attr("fill","none")
            .attr("stroke","#ADADAD")
            .attr("d",diagonal); 

</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the example, however I still see the initial point to be positioned at the left center of the layout, and what I would really need is to start at the top center.